# How to convert an excel formula into macro vba code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

How do I convert below into macro vba code? 
    =INDEX(CLASSIFICATION,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(NAMES,O12)),0))

I have a column (O) in Sheet1 which it needs to be searched from. I have two columns in sheet2 that is defined with a name (Names and Classification). When a name is found in Column O of Sheet1, Column P have corresponding value from Sheet2 classification

Sheet1 Column O
our client's name is John Doe

Sheet2
Name         Classification
John Doe        Class A

Sheet1 Column P will have the value Class A

Please help!

Comment: Post the task (source data, desured result), not alternative solution.

Comment: to use worksheet functions in vba, use the WorksheetFunction property of the Application object. documentation here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction so your answer is Application.WorksheetFunction.INDEX(CLASSIFICATION,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(NAMES,O12)),0))

Answer (score 1):

Since sample data is not available therefore I'm assuming,,

- `Sheet 1` Column `O`, Names to be searched in `O2:O10`.
- `Sheet 2` has `Clasification`  & `Names`, are `Named range` in `A2:A10` & `B2:B10`.
- You need results in range `P2:P10` in `Sheet1`.

*Now first, I would like to suggest how to assign Excel Formula to VBA code.*

```
Range("P2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Clasification,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Names,O2)),0)),""No Found"")"
```

**N.B.** You need an Array (CSE) formula so that `.FormulaArray` has been used.

---

*But since `Named Range` is/are need to be declared while using with VBA Macro, therefore I would like to recommend you the following code to use as `Standard Module`.*

```
Sub Formula()

Dim Clasification As Range
Dim Names As Range


 Set Clasification = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A10")
 Set Names = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B10")


Range("P2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Clasification,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Names,O2)),0)),""No Found"")"
Range("P2:P10").FillDown
End Sub
```

*Adjust cell references & Named Ranges in the code as needed.*